# Play! async action akka AskTimeoutException

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I am trying to make the simplest async request using an akka Actor using the ask pattern but I keep receiving the `akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException` no matter what. What I have is this:

```
object Users extends Controller {

  def newUser = {
    val actor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[UserRegistration])
    ActorAction[String](actor, "hello")(Ok(_))
  }
}
```

where the `ActorAction` is a wrapper of the usual `Async`:

```
object ActorAction {

  def apply[A](actorRef: ActorRef, msg: AnyRef, timeout: Timeout = 5 seconds)(f: A => Result)(implicit m: Manifest[A]): Action[AnyContent] = {
    Action {
      AsyncResult {
        ask(actorRef, msg, timeout).mapTo[A].asPromise.map(f)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And the actor does nothing but logs the receiving message and returns it:

```
class UserRegistration extends Actor {
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)
  def receive = {
    case u => log.info("received " + u); u
  }
}
```

The logging of the message works just fine. I have tried everything but nothing works. Any help is more than welcome!

Play: 2.9.1
Akka: 2.0.2

Stacktrace:

```
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ss_dev
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[info] play - Starting application default Akka system.
[INFO] [12/28/2012 22:10:42.51] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1] [akka://application/user/$a] received hello
[error] play - Waiting for a promise, but got an error: Timed out
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out
at akka.dispatch.DefaultPromise.result(Future.scala:875) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.dispatch.Await$.result(Future.scala:74) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaPromise.await(Akka.scala:43) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise$class.await(Promise.scala:55) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaPromise.await(Akka.scala:28) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise$class.value(Promise.scala:53) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out
at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:274) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.actor.DefaultScheduler$$anon$6$$anon$7.run(Scheduler.scala:183) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:94) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1381) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not replying to the message `sender ! u`, please read the Akka Reference Documentation: http://doc.akka.io

Comment: Thanks Viktor! It did work! I thought the return value of the receive method was the "reply". Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Gerry, the receive method doesn't return anything (Unit), this is because you could have 0..N "return values"